# Functions don't exist in filter on observable in Angular2

Tags: angular, reactive-programming

I have the following code that looks for a term and then returns elements from an array that contains that string. However, I get the following error when I run this: **user.indexOf is not a function**

Do some built in functions not work in filter when using it on Observables?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Person } from '../person';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserSearchService {

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

  search(term: string): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.af.database.list('/users')
      .map(users => {
        return users.filter(user => {
          return user.indexOf(term) > -1;
        })
      })
  }

}
```

Comment: Is user a string? From the looks of it, I'm guessing it's some other kind of object which would explain why indexOf is not a method on it

Comment: Based on the signature of the method, user is of type Person, and Person probably doesn't have any indexOf method.

Comment: Ahh of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `user` is not a string but some other object (probably of type `Person` based on your import statement). Call `indexOf` on the appropriate string property of `user`. So something like this:

```
...
return user.name.indexOf(term) > -1
...
```